# Unable to resolve action `google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master`, unable to find version `master`

Tags: firebase, github, google-cloud-firestore, yaml, github-actions

I'm using this code in Github actions to Backup firebase on Google Cloud

```
name: Backup Firestore

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '41 16 * * *'

env:
  PROJECT_ID: polydds-b712c
  BUCKET: gs://backup_polydts01

jobs:
  backup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
      with:
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
        export_default_credentials: true
    - run: gcloud info
    - run: gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID
    - run: gcloud firestore export $BUCKET
```

However I get this error

Unable to resolve action `google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master`, unable to find version `master`

I changed master to main and v1 to test if it works

I got this error

```
Run gcloud firestore export $BUCKET
  gcloud firestore export $BUCKET
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    PROJECT_ID: polydds-b712c
    BUCKET: gs://backup_polydts01
    CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT: github-actions-setup-gcloud
    CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT_VERSION: 1.1.0
ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.export) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials.

If you have already logged in with a different account:

    $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have no clue what's wrong?
My Master branch is up to date and working
any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Use `google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@main` as there's no `master` branch there. See https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud.

Comment: Also, in the [Usage](https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud#usage), it's using `@v1`.

Comment: @v1 ? or #main ?

Comment: You may use either one of them i.e. branch or version.

Comment: both didn't work 

On v1 I got this error, updated in the question

Comment: Yes, it did work. It's now past that `setup-gcloud` step. And, now your workflow is failing at the last export step. Those error messages are also pointing towards the fact that the `auth` is missing from your workflow. Please go through the docs of https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud. There are examples that you can use according to your use case.